# AttributeError: 'ChannelPromise'object has no attribute '__value__'kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: [Errno 111] Connectionrefused Flask-redis-celery

Tags: wsl-2, celery-task, connection-refused, redis-server, flask-celery

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRrpK.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/q20Kw.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iPaA.png)

Everything is running fine.But end up with this error and not able to proceed with celery

Expected the celery task to run and return the task id

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ho0EI.png)

[Initialised this with the flask app instance in main.py]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/up8t1.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0K7mb.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIDEY.png)
[Error]